# Concatenated Observables (RxJava ) with flapMap

Tags: java, android, reactjs, rx-java

I have some concatenated observable using flatMap such as

```
api.call1()
.flatMap{a-> api.call2(a)}
.flatMap{b-> api.call3(a,b) //<- no access to a}
```

the issue is that In third concatenated call I need what I got from previous one but also the result from the first one

this is the scheme:
A->(a)->B->(b)-> C( needs **b** but also **a**)->...

I try to solve it out like that :

1 approach ( nested 3rd observable inside the 2nd one)

```
api.call1()
    .flatMap{a-> api.call2(a).flatMap{b-> api.call3(a,b)}}
```

it works but I know that this is not a good approach (because of passing parms from outside of the pipe)

2 approach (better but a lot of boilerplate)

```
api.call1().flatMap{ a-> 
    Observable.combineLatest(Observable.just(a),api.call2(a),
          BiFunction{  a,b -> Pair(a,b)})
           .flatMap(pair:Pair<A,B> -> api.call3(pair.first,pair.second))
}}
```

anybody know better approach (some fashion operator)

Thanks everybody sory for my poor ingles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a second overload of `flatMap` which takes both the input and the output.  You can then combine these into a `Pair` to send to the next `flatMap`

```
api.call1()
    .flatMap( 
        { a -> api.call2(a) },
        { a, b -> new Pair(a, b) }
    )
    .flatMap { pair-> api.call3(pair.first, pair.second) }
```